# Straight line path in swift

Tags: swift

I need the help i have this code this is doing circular path but what i need is straight line i tried to do this but unsuccessful.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {



    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let orbit = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")
    var affineTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0.0)
    affineTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(affineTransform, CGFloat(M_PI))
    let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: 150 - (100/2),y: 150 - (100/2)), radius:  CGFloat(150), startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle:CGFloat(M_PI * 2), clockwise: true)

    orbit.circlePath = path.CGPath
    orbit.duration = 8
    orbit.additive = true
    orbit.repeatCount = 0.25
    orbit.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced
    orbit.rotationMode = kCAAnimationRotateAuto

    moveobj.layer .addAnimation(orbit, forKey: "orbit")
}
```

and more one question how to do this disappear after finished to move.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easy do this using a CAShapeLayer.

```
    let line = CAShapeLayer()
    let linePath = UIBezierPath()
    linePath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100))
    linePath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 300, y: 300))
    line.path = linePath.cgPath
    line.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(line)
```

First, create a CAShapeLayer.
Second, create a UIBezierPath to define your line's path.
Third, move the bezier path to a starting point.
Fourth, add the ending point of the bezier path.
fifth, apply the bezier path to the CAShapeLayer.
Sixth, apply a stroke color so you can see the line when you add it as a sublayer.
Finally, add it is a sublayer of the view.

Comment: where i put this ? and i don´t what to draw a straight line i want to move object in straight line can yo help me pls. Thanks